# Remove elements of one list from other list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have one list with points. I am applying:

```
var result = neighbors.SelectMany(element => GenerateNeighbors(element)).Distinct<Point3D>().ToList<Point3D>();
```

To generate all neighbors from each point of this list. But I have another list with other points, and this neighbor-generation can generate points already add to that one.

How to I remove from result list the repeated elements from the other list? Any linq function with some predicate I can use to improve this?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**
 New code:

```
    class Point3D : IEquatable<Point3D>
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int Z { get; set; }
        public bool visited { get; set; }
        public int life { get; set; }

        public Point3D(int _x, int _y, int _z)
        {
            this.X = _x;
            this.Y = _y;
            this.Z = _z;
            this.visited = false;
            this.life = 2;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Point3D obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override Boolean Equals(object o)
        {
            if (!(o is Point3D)) return false;
            return Equals((Point3D)o);
        }

        public Boolean Equals(Point3D p)
        {
            return Equals(this, p);
        }

        public static Boolean Equals(Point3D a, Point3D b)
        {
            return a.X == b.X && a.Y == b.Y && a.Z == b.Z;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why the GetHashCode not implemented function?  Does this overwrite the base GetHashCode method, and will it interfere with storing your Point3D objects in collections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Linq [`Except()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) extension method:

```
result = result.Except(otherList).ToList();
```

Your `Point3D` class should provide an appropriate implementation of `Equals` / `GetHashCode` (yes, you do have to implement it, throwing a `NotImplementedException` won't work) or implement (more explicit) [`IEquatable<Point3D>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) for this to work, or alternatively you can pass a custom `IEqualityComparer` as second parameter to `Except()`

Comment: And is this the case? Am I implementing the comparer correctly? I dont think so because I have a "if (!pointsInSurface.Contains(neighbors[i]))" and I am adding many times the same points to this pointsInSurface list. How should I code it?

Comment: @Pedro: The comparer should be a separate class - you probably were looking to implement `IEQuatable<Point3D>` instead.

Comment: @PedroDusso: You still need to implement `GetHashCode()`  - since you have three int's could be just  `return X.GetHashCode() ^ Y.GetHashCode() ^ Z.GetHashCode();`